# Animations of Subviews in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

haii i have 5 subviews in a viewcontroller,each subvies are shown when corresponding button are clicked.But normally when i button is clicked,it shows the subview without animating or tansistion .I need to give a effect for the subview when it popup.
i tried this but no luck

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"page transition" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:NoteView cache:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:NoteView];
```

in button click.is there any way to animate like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be using blocks for animation, look at

```
transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:
```

in UIView, with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp` as one of the option masks

Comment: instead of putting animation code inside begin and commit calls, you should be containing it all within blocks, apples docs give a good description [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add commitAnimation method

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"page transition" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:NoteView cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:NoteView];
[UIView commitAnimation];
```

Comment: i got an errro that commitanimation not found (return type default to id)

Comment: sorry it should be [UIView commitAnimations];